# Using python to parsing a log file with real case - how to skip lines in csv.reader for loop, how to use different delimiter

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

Here is a section of the log file I want to parse:

[image]

And here is the code I am writing:

```
import csv

with open('Coplanarity_PedCheck.log','rt') as tsvin, open('YX2.csv', 'wt') as csvout:
    read_tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    for row in read_tsvin:
        print(row)
        filters = row[0]
        if "#Log File Initialized!" in filters:
            print(row)
            datetime = row[0]
            print("looklook",datetime[23:46])
            csvout.write(datetime[23:46]+",")
            BS = row[0]
            print("looklook",BS[17:21])
            csvout.write(datetime[17:21]+",")
            csvout.write("\n")
    csvout.close()
```

I need to get the date and time information from row1, then get "left" from row2, then need to skip section 4. How should I do it?

Since the `csv.reader` makes row1 an list with only 1 element I converted it to string again to split out the datetime info I need. But I think it is not efficient.

I did same thing for row2, then I want to skip row 3-6, but I don't know how.

Also, `csv.reader` converts my float data into text, how can I convert them back before I write them into another file?

Comment: please, add you log and desired output not as image but as a code snippet

Comment: This is a very data specific question. My smell is, if you can change the way logs are output, you'll avoid lots of trouble

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to learn to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#module-re).

For example, you could do something like this:

```
with open('Coplanarity_PedCheck.log','rt') as tsvin, open('YX2.csv', 'wt') as csvout:
    read_tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    # Get the first line and use the first field
    header = read_tsvin.next()[0]
    m = re.search('\[([0-9: -]+)\]', row)
    datetime = m.group(1)
    csvout.write(datetime, ',')

    # Find if 'Left' is in line 1
    direction = read_tsvin.next()[0]
    m = re.search('Left', direction)
    if m:
        # If m is found print the whole line
        csvout.write(m.group(0))
    csvout.write('\n')

    # Skip lines 3-6
    for i in range(4):
        null = read_tsvin.next()

    # Loop over the rest of the rows
    for row in tsvin:
        # Parse the data

    csvout.close()
```

Modifying this to look for a line containing '#Log File Initialized!' rather than hard coding for the first line would be fairly simple using regular expressions. Take a look at the regular expression documentation

This probably isn't exactly what you want to do, but rather a suggestion for a good starting point.

Comment: I managed to get through the skip line method. Now I have another problem. For section 6, I want to read all 9 rows and write it into another csv file as one row with "," as delimiter. My code as below which can only print row by row...
for row in read_tsvin:
                checkendline = str(row[0])
                if 'END' in checkendline:
                    row = next(read_tsvin)
                    break
                else:
                    write_csvout=csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',')
                    write_csvout.writerow(row)
                    print (write_csvout)

Comment: @user5963823 That is different enough from the original question that you should probably post a new question. You might want to look at [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to combine all elements into a single list before writing.